# How to make a list of foreign key objects in Entityframework

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm developing in asp.net core 2 webApi with mysql DB (code first)

In my application I have models:

- **country** : that has: Id, Name.
- **element** : that one of it's variables should be `List<Country> countries`

The problem is that when the database is created the relation that it does is:
in country I have elementId and countries will be duplicated

Should I create element_country model that will have : elementId, CountryId?

If so, how should I pass the object to the view without creating special viewmodel for that purpose,

I believe it's something small that I am missing and I would appreciate the help.

Thanks

Comment: This is a many-to-many association so yes, you need a junction record.

Comment: @GertArnold and the only why is to create model for that ?

Comment: Yes. In ef-core there's no other option.

Comment: @viveknuna it's a collection of countries so CountryId would not help in that case.

Comment: @GertArnold, thanks. (seems like a big issue)

Comment: @LeonBarkan sorry I missed it. Mapping table should be a good choice.

Comment: @viveknuna , thanks. will be done